# Changing the color of URLs in strings affected by regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the color of URLs matched by some [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) within strings.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Change the color of words containing the @ sing
    $("#modal_0 section p").html(function(_, html){
        return html.replace(/(\@\w+)/g, '<span class="change_color">$1</span>');
    }); //Works fine

    //Change the color of words containing URLs (www.domain.com, domain.com, etc.)
    $("#modal_0 section p").html(function(_, html){
        return html.replace(/^(?=www\.)?[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9.\/%&=\?_:;-]+$/, '<span class="change_color">$1</span>');
    }); //Doesn't work
})
;
```

The function works fine when I try to catch words containing the @ sing. And I don't see any problem with the regex.

***Here is*** [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JssZm/).

Comment: Your regex does not match -> http://rubular.com/r/UaMiO4Ppxb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove those anchors, add a capturing group, and it will work:

```
/(?=www\.)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9.\/%&=\?_:;-]+)/
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JssZm/1/**

Comment: Hey thanks, this works. On a related note, do you think that regex is enough to detect most urls? Even the ones that are compressed?

Comment: @Aaron: You'll get a lot of false positives, so I would try looking for `http:` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/JssZm/3/

Comment: Right, so I'll have to listen directly for .com, .net, etc.. Just after the dot instead of +[A-Za-z0-9.\/%&=\?_:;-] Is that what you mean? And if so can you give a hint in how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex was not proper, it had `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end meaning it will match only those `p` which had the domain name as the only content like `somedomain.com`.

Also you missed to add a capturing group.

```
//Change the color of words containing urls (www.domain.com,domain.com,etc)
$("#modal_0 section p").html(function(_, html){
    return html.replace(/(?=www\.)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9.\/%&=\?_:;-]+)/, '<span class="change_color">$1</span>');   
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4P2BN/)